# TFS WebPortal issue on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tfs

I am having a issue with Chrome in that User Stories are not getting populated with any details ever since got updated to latest version of Chrome (Version 55.0.2883.75 m)

I cant roll back to a previous version of chrome and I can use IE11 as a workaround but would like to try and get Chrome working:

With DEV Tools open this is the error getting fired in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at f._generateTransition (TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls.min.js?__loc=en-US:formatted:3785)
    at f._generateTransitions (TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls.min.js?__loc=en-US:formatted:3763)
    at f.bindToWorkItem (TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls.min.js?__loc=en-US:formatted:3674)
    at e.invalidate (TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls.min.js?__loc=en-US:formatted:3264)
    at e.a.bind (TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls.min.js?__loc=en-US:formatted:2630)
    at e.<anonymous> (TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls.min.js?__loc=en-US:formatted:751)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.6.2a.min.js:28)
    at b.bind (TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls.min.js?__loc=en-US:formatted:750)
    at TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls.min.js?__loc=en-US:formatted:1507
    at TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls.min.js?__loc=en-US:formatted:1612
```

This is the js in question and the line with my comment is where the error occurs:

```
    f.prototype._generateTransition = function(f, a) {
        var c = a.getRev(), b;
        e.assert(a.stateChanged() || a.getRev() === 0, "ActionSet provided does not represent a change in state.");
        b = {
            revision: c,
            owner: a.changedByName,
            date: d.DateUtils.localeFormat(a.getChangedDate(), "d"),
            reason: f.getFieldValueByRevision(g.CoreField.Reason, c),
            resultingState: null
        };
        if (c === 0)
            b.resultingState = f.getFieldValueByRevision(g.CoreField.State, 0);
        else {
            e.assert(a.stateChanged());
            b.resultingState = a.stateChanges[1] // a.stateChanges is null
        }
        return b
```

Any one experience the same issue or have any idea what a possible fix would be for Chrome.  As I say not a show stopper as I can just use a different browser.

Comment: Did you mean you can work with  a previous version of chrome and just not work with the latest version ? Did this error  also occurs  on others machine. If so, this may related to chrome side. If not, there maybe something wrong with your installation.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Yes, it worked fine with a previous version of Chrome.  I can't roll back to that version.  It is happening across the organisation - everyone who got Chrome update is seeing the same behaviour

Comment: What's your detail version of TFS? It works fine on my TFS2017 with the same chrome version.  Are you using a customize work item or just the default one?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT - using TFS2012 - Don't believe it is a customized work item but I could be wrong on that - is there an easy way to determine this?

Comment: @ctrl_alt_defeat, I would recommend that you upgrade your TFS server. 2012, is 4 major versions behind...thats a lot...

Comment: @MrHinsh that would be the goal however it wont be happening any time soon.  It works fine in IE11.  It worked in Chrome up.until this latest update so I was really looking to try and figure out what has caused this too break

Comment: Since your 2012 TFS has not been updated in a number of years I would guess that it does not support the latest version of Chrome. You can either roll back the Chrome update or Update TFS. If you need help then give me a shout.

Comment: @MrHinsh - as I mentioned in the question I can't roll back company wide update of Chrome for this and we won't be moving to a newer version of TFS anytime soon.  Looks like I'll have to stick with IE11 as my work around

Comment: (just wondering) Why not upgrade TFS? Its free, and relatively easy...what is the blocker that has had you stay on 2012?

Comment: I noticed the same issue recently. 

We do have plans to do an upgrade, but it's a fairly extensive project and have a large developer ecosystem dependent on it, so we're proceeding cautiously.

Was looking to see if there's a chrome://flags/ setting that might revert the behavior of whatever changed from v54 to v55 that broke TFS 2012.

Comment: @TariqAhmed - keep me posted if you find anything - might be worth opening an issue with the chrome team

Comment: Your developer ecosystem would be dependant on VS 2012 and not TFS version. VS 2012 is supported connecting to TFS 2017...

Comment: Did you figure out this issue?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT No never figured it out.  Workaround of IE11 just

Answer (score 0):

You may need to disable Add Block as it is known to interfere with some Javascript applications.